# What is the meaning and significance of "urubutinga" in Mário de Andrade's "O lundu do escritor difícil"

Tags: meaning, poetry, mario-de-andrade, portuguese-language

The title is suggestive enough to elicit an understanding that Andrade probably purposefully made this poem difficult to read for people who are not familiar with Tupi culture. A conscious effort of Mário de Andrade to **rebuke the Eurocentric mindset** is evidenced by the abundant symbolic imagery.<sup>1</sup>

> Virtude de urubutinga
> De enxergar tudo de longe!
> Não carece vestir tanga
> Pra penetrar meu caçanje!
> Você sabe o francês "singe"
> Mas não sabe o que é guariba?
> — Pois é macaco, seu mano,
> Que só sabe o que é da estranja.

What does "urubutinga" mean here? What does it refer to? Shouldn't it be "urubitinga" aka the [great black hawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_black_hawk) native to Brazil?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>See for example Alfredo Cesar Melo's discussion in "The Predicaments of Transculturation: A Materialist Reading of “Meu tio o Iauaretê” by João Guimarães Rosa"</sub>